# Add build number to package version with `dotnet pack` in VSTS Build process

Tags: versioning, azure-pipelines, .net-standard

With a .NET Framework library you could specify a version with a wildcard and NUGET pack command would append the build date and version automatically when running a NUGET Build Task in VSTS.

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

NUGET PACK would generate a NUPKG file with a version like `1.0.6604.1234` appending the date number and a build ID.

#### NET Standard issues

In .NET Core and .NET standard the new `.csproj` format does not support this wildcard format.

We can't package with Nuget.exe (reason: [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481)) but we can use `dotnet pack`  except I need to auto-increment the build numbers. The `dotnet` Build Task in VSTS allows me to wholly replace the version number, but I want to retain the version in the csproj file, and just append a build number (as I used to).

I found that using `<VersionPrefix>x.y</VersionPrefix>` in the csproj file would work with `nuget pack` and I could then add the additional parameter `VersionSuffix=$(Build.BuildNumber)` to the pack task.

All looked good until the first dev updated the project version in the project properties dialog. Visual Studio ignored the VersionPrefix and set the `<Version>` tag - and the build number fix is ignored because a `Version` tag exists.

Is there a way to read the `Version` from the csproj? If so I could set the build property to `Version=$(ProjectVersion).$(Build.BuildNumber)` ?

Or are there alternative ways to handle auto-incrementing the build version when packaging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @patricklu-msft for his suggestions.

There is it appears no built-in way to emulate the wildcard behaviour we previously had `NUGET pack` with `dotnet pack`, nor was there way to get the `<Version>` tag out of the project file.

So I've created a new VSTS Build task that does this: [VersionTaskReader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=conficient.VersionReaderTask) in the MarketPlace.

This extension can be pointed to a `.csproj` or `.vbproj` and will set an environment variable `VERSION`, and `VERSION_BUILD` which has the `BUILDID` appended. You can optionally add a prefix to make each instance different if needed.

For example, if your project contains `<Version>1.1</Version>` then the `VERSION_BUILD` would be something like `1.1.8680`

Then the `dotnet pack` task can use the environment variable `VERSION_BUILD` in the versioning options screen, so that the build number automatically increments.

Answer (score 10):

First you can select `Use an environment variable` for **Automatic package versioning**, use your defined variable such as `temp` (`$(build.buildNumber)`) as **Environment variable**.

[image]
[image]

More details take a look at this link: [Dotnet pack automatic package versioning build number clarification](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5655)

Another way is using the "arguments" field in the dotnet CLI task, you can pass additional arguments to the dotnet cli.

> Using `--version-suffix $(Build.BuildNumber)` will pass the build
>   number as version suffix. Make sure you don't have a `<version>`
>   element set in your csproj, but rather a `<versionprefix>` element.
>   The built version will look like `versionprefix-versionsuffix`, so for
>   example, if you have `<versionprefix>1.2.3</versionprefix>` and build
>   number `201805002`, the built version will be `1.2.3-201805002`. In this case do not select the automatic package versioning.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did know about the option to use environment var, but this doesn't allow me to use the Version from the csproj, only the VersionPrefix - which as I mentioned is easily overlooked by staff.

Comment: @Quango Have you tried this solution: Edit .csproj and set `<Version>1.0.0$(VersionSuffix)</Version>` and 
`dotnet pack --version-suffix -XXX` The logic is defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/94a3f2856cb09e66ee7472820b4e26fb576b4686/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.DefaultAssemblyInfo.targets#L18-L22). Details please refer this question in github: [Unable to use <Version> in .csproj with --version-suffix during dotnet pack](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5681).

Comment: @Quango Also suggest you take a look at this thread: [dotnet build --version-suffix not working?](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3778)